# Use GetTokenAsync wih custom authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am currently using a custom authentication system, and in one of my controller, I would like to use `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync` to retrieve my token.

I would like to use it like so:
`HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(MyOAuthAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "access_token")`

Where in my authentication system do I assign my token value to `"access_token"` to be able to retrieve it like this?

Is it returning it from a custom Claim?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tokens will be saved to `AuthenticationProperties` in cookie :

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "xxxx"),
    new Claim("FullName", "xxxxx"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>
{
    new AuthenticationToken {Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken, Value = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
    new AuthenticationToken {Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken, Value = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
};
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
authProperties.StoreTokens(tokens);



await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    authProperties);
```

And get by :

```
var access_token =await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "access_token");
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't have to be with cookies though. You can create a ticket like so `new AuthenticationTicket(principal, properties, Scheme.Name);`